Proof that B is a lattice basis iff the fundamental parallelepided contains no non-zero lattice vector: unclear step
I have just started studying lattice-based cryptography and came across a proof that is unclear. Given a set $B=\{b_1, \dots, b_n\}$ of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$, define the fundamental parallelepiped
$$P(B) = \{Bx | x \in \mathbb{R}^n, 0 \leq x_i < 1 \; \forall i \in \{1,\dots,m\} \}$$
A standard result says that $B$ is a basis for a lattice $L$ iff $P(B)$ contains no non-zero vector that's also in $L$. Thus, if we assume that $P(B) \bigcap L = \{0\}$, we should be able to prove that $B$ is a basis for $L$. The standard way to prove this is the following:

Take a vector $v \in L$ and write it as a linear combination of $B$'s vectors. Then for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $v = By$.
Define $y' = (y_1' \dots y_n')^T$, with $y_i'=y_i - \lfloor y_i \rfloor$ (here $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the floor function).
Since $By \in L$ and $t=\sum_{i \in \{1,\dots,n\}} \lfloor y_i \rfloor \cdot b_i \in L$, the proof concludes that $By'=By-t \in L$.
Finally, $By'$ is clearly an element of $P(B)$. By assumption, it must follow that $By'=0$.
It in turn follows that $By$ is an integral linear combination of $B$'s vectors, and that must hold for any lattice point. The thesis follows.

I found this proof in Regev's public lecture notes https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/introduction.pdf. What is unclear to me, is the claim that $t \in L$. It is true that $t$ is an integral linear combination of $B$'s vectors, but in principle we have no guarantees that an integral combination of $B$'s vector is a lattice point. That would be the case if B was a basis, but that's exactly what we aim to prove. What am I missing?

To elaborate a little on Ost's answer: As Regev's notes define them, a lattice in $\mathbb R^n$ is the $\mathbb Z$-span of a basis $B$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Thus if $B = \{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ the lattice associated to it is $\Lambda(B):=\{\sum_{i=1}^n n_i b_i: n_i\in \mathbb Z, 1\leq i\leq n\}$.
Now if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are bases of $\mathbb R^n$, then it may well happen that $\Lambda(B_1)=\Lambda(B_2)$ even if $B_1\neq B_2$, so it is natural to try to understand, for a given lattice $\Lambda$, the set $\{B: B \text{ is a basis of  } \mathbb R^n \text{ and } \Lambda =\Lambda(B)\}$. Any such $B$ must clearly satisfy

$B$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $B \subseteq \Lambda$.

However this is not sufficient, as the example of $\{e_1,2e_2\}$ shows for the lattice $\mathbb Ze_1 \oplus \mathbb Ze_2 \subseteq \mathbb R^2$. In order to get necessary and sufficient conditions for a set to be a basis of a given lattice $\Lambda$ you must add some further condition, and one possibility is to use the parallelpiped $P(B) = \{v\in\mathbb R^n: v=\sum_{i=1}^n t_i b_i, t_i \in [0,1)\}$ associate to $B$, where the condition is:

$P(B)\cap \Lambda= \{0\}$.

The step in the proof that these conditions are sufficient uses $t =\sum_{I=1}^n \lfloor y_i \rfloor b_i$ and this lies in $\Lambda$ because $\Lambda$ is closed under vector addition and the $b_i$ lie in $\Lambda$.

Thanks for the clarification. Now I realize I missed that detail. So in a nutshell, the correct full statement should be "if B's vectors are in L and linearly independent, and L's intersection with B only contains 0, B is a basis for L,". Right?

@HiddenInPublic: pretty much, but I think you have a typo in your full statement - it should be L's intersection with P(B), and obviously you want B to be a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ so it must be linearly independent and have size $n$ thus "if B is a set of n vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ and i) $B\subset L$, ii) B is linearly independent, and iii) L's intersection with P(B) only contains 0, then B is a basis for L".

The statement in Regev's notes assumes that the elements of $B$ lie in $L$. Without this assumption the statement that you are trying to prove is incorrect.
